# How to pass controller Function variable to Datepicker Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am new to Angularjs. I have put 2 Datepickers. I need that When I select date from first datepicker then the smaller dates from that date should be disabled in second Datepicker. I am unable to set "minDate" for second Datepicker directive.

Below is my code :

**HTML Code :**

```
<div ng-controller='TestController'>

  <label>From Date :</label>
  <input type="text" id="1" datepicker="" ng-init="variable=''"
         ng-model="startDate" ng-change="test()" />

  <label>To Date :</label>
  <input type="text" id="2" callFuc="test()" datepicker1=""
         ng-model="endDate" />
</div>
```

**Js Code:**

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.test = function() {
    $scope.variable = $scope.startDate;
    $window.alert("From date is" + $scope.variable);
  };
});

app.directive('datepicker', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
      $('#1').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive('datepicker1', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
      $('#2').datepicker({
        minDate: scope.test(),
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I am able to disable past dates in first Datepicker using `minDate : "0"`.
But I am unable to set `minDate` properly for the second Datepicker. I am not able to fetch selected date from the First Datepicker and pass it to "datepicker1" directive. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

---

### Update

I have updated code. Kindly review it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ohCFzpwLGgFPPH49jybq?p=preview

Comment: Which jQuery datepicker library does the code use?

Comment: jquery ui datepicker

Answer (score 1):

The datepicker directive needs to watch for changes and update `minDate` as needed:

```
app.directive('datepicker1', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
      scope.$watch(attr.minDate, function(value) {    
          el.datepicker({
            minDate: value,
            onSelect: function(dateText) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
              });
            }
          });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
  <label>To Date :</label>
  <input type="text" min-date="variable" datepicker1
         ng-model="endDate" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried this code. value is coming proper as per the Date changed from the first Date picker. But for the second datepicker, all dates are coming enabled. It seems that minDate is not getting that value

Comment: The next step would be to create a [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated code. Kindly review it. http://plnkr.co/edit/ohCFzpwLGgFPPH49jybq?p=preview